# WSO2IS refresh session via API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are currently using WSO2IS 5.3.0 for authentication, and using Pac4J as a session cache in our application. Each API touches the session cache to keep alive the Pac4J session (so it expires after N minutes of inactivity).

Can the WSO2 session cache be touched in the same way? If so, what's the best method to do so (without too much chatter between WSO2 and our application)?

Comment: What is the protocol you are using? SAML, OAuth2, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Pac4J session is expired you have send authentication request to WSO2 Identity server as per the protocol you are using SAML, OAuth2 ...etc. At the time you send authentication request if IDP session already expired you will be redirected to authentication (login page). If IDP session is not expired you will get authenticated assertion without re-authentication. You can refer [1] about how to control IDP session.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Session+Timeout